# SKTexture with RGB5A1 for optimisation

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

As I understand from `init(data pixelData: NSData, size size: CGSize)` method description:

> An NSData object that holds the bitmap data. The pixels must be 32
>   bpp, 8bpc (unsigned integer) RGBA pixel data. The color components
>   should have been already multiplied by the alpha value.

`SKTexture` always use RGB8888 format. Is it possible to switch to another format to reduce memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be an way to load a texture with anything other than a 32BPP pixel format in SpriteKit (24BPP just ignores the alpha byte). But, it is possible to build texture compression on top of existing SpriteKit textures using a shader, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38679128/763355) for specifics on how to do that.