# Which program or format to use for texture compression

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image

I have big image textures (4-12MB) and have resized them as much as I can without losing too much detail and would like to further compress them. Online compressors compress the 12.6MB image to 6MB without any problems, but Xcode doesn't support it (even though the compressed image is still .png), apparently because indexed color spaces are not supported for bitmap graphics contexts (according to `CGBitmapContextCreate` documentation and another post) and the compressed image uses them. If I try to use it I get an error:

> CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported color space.

I was looking through Apple documentation about compression and supported formats, but all I can find is information about how to compress images in code. I want to be able to apply an compressed (or otherwise reduced in size) image in the editor itself and not later in code. Is this possible?

If it is not possible to do this using a program, how should this be done via code in Swift? I found a lot of objective-C posts about this, but none that uses Swift.

Comment: If you want to translate a code from OBJ-C to Swift, you should try    https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/main - Swiftify.

Comment: If you are loading textures into SpriteKit, have a look at this texture optimization framework for iOS. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38679128/763355

Answer (score 0):

> Important: iOS does not support device-independent or generic color spaces. iOS applications must use device color spaces instead.

Use `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB` as the color space.