# Displaying LOTS of thumbnails on iOS/tvOS?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, core-animation, thumbnails, tvos

To isolate the question I'm asking:

- assume that I have local access to all the pre rendered thumbnails.
- think: outermost view on the built-in Photos app.
- the thumbnails may need to animate in some way(s)
- doesn't need to scroll

The most obvious class is `UICollectionView` used as a grid view.  But I'm wondering if `SpriteKit` would work, or possibly `SceneKit`. iOS is the primary target, but tvOS support would be awesome

I need it to be performant for the animations, obviously, which is why i'm considering `SpriteKit` at all.

It would be a monumental task for me to tackle the ins and outs of `Metal` and `MetalKit`, so I'm hoping someone out there has experience with putting approx 1500 images on a screen, animating them into place from off screen.

Comment: Well, the most obvious problem you are going to have with 1500 animation is memory management. You could take a look here for one possible solution under SpriteKit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38679128/763355

Comment: Will take a look.  Would it be feasible to put 1500 sublayers into a single view and manage those myself?  OLD OLD AppKit used a single/few NSCell to overlay a larger number table cells to essentially blit the contents onto the screen.

Comment: Well, you are never going to get all of those animation/images on screen at the same time due to limited memory. I assume you must have some type o scrolling or something, so the key will be to set things up first and then only hold the specific ones that you need at any one time depending on the view bbox. The problem is memory use, you have to address that root issue and you will likely need to hold decoded data in mmap() memory so as not to consume all the ram directly.

Comment: I can get away with using `imageNamed()`, which uses `NSCache`. At least for a first go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Animation and SpriteKit were both designed (quite explicitly in the case of Core Animation) to handle this sort of design idea.

Perhaps not to the scale of 1500 screens, but Moore's Law is probably on your side. And the size of the images, too.

Both of these frameworks can present short quicktime encoded movies, which alleviates much of the memory problem, and they can decode lots of them, on the fly, especially if they're of small dimensions. And this is going to be the case when you optimise for your view congested with 1500 "screens".

But I'd suggest putting them together, in batches of 15 or 30 "screens", and doing hit testing to determine which one's been touched. Which is going to be hell for users... because:

If the little movie screens are the same aspect as the presenting scene, then you'd have them at about 50 x 28 pixels in size. On an iPhone xPlus model, that's TINY!

by way of example, here's 1500 units on a 1920x1080 image. Drop this on your iPhone Plus and see if you can touch just one of them...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input.  As for touching/selecting "just one",  a) interaction at that level is something I've already considered and b) there are existing solutions for this kind of thing (i.e., the Photos app)